# What is this long thin mark on my lens, fungus or dust?

Tags: lens, film, fungus

What is this long thin mark on my lens, fungus or dust?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like a scratch to me, but neither picture is clear enough. Have you already cleaned this? It looks like it's had a hard life.

Comment: I haven’t cleaned it. I just bought it 2 weeks ago. I’ll take another photo of it and post it again but that’s the best I got for now, really hard to see with the naked eye.

Comment: Try lighting it from the side at about a 60° angle to the camera.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the lighting and focus makes it difficult to tell. But just based on the upload photo, it looks like either a fine piece of lint or dust stuck to the inside of the rear element.

Comment: Thanks! My thoughts too. I was thinking it’s just a dust but I just want to make sure though. It’s actually hard to see, it took me a couple of minutes to notice it.